# Develop Hive CDH5 withThrift,not connect server

Tags: hive, kerberos, thrift

I want to use thrift for the metestore of hive cdh5.out big data of platform is CDH5.5.2,and security use Kerberos.for example:

- `getAllDatabases`
- `execute(sql)`
- `create_database`
- `get_database(String name)`

and so on ...

`hive.server2.thrift.port=10000`

**Code:**

```java
public class HiveClient {
    public static final String SERVER_IP = "hadoop7";
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 10000;
    public static final int TIMEOUT = 30000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TTransport transport = null;
        try {
            transport = new TSocket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT, TIMEOUT);
            TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
            ThriftHive.Client client=new ThriftHive.Client(protocol);
            transport.open();
            List<String> databases=client.get_all_databases();
            for(String database:databases){
                System.out.println(database);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (null != transport) {
                transport.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: Is your Hiveserver2 running?.You cannot execute queries through metastore and metastore used port 9083 by default.

Comment: The Hive Metastore has a Java API, that encapsulates that Thrift nightmare. Just use it > http://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.1.1/api/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/HiveMetaStoreClient.html

Comment: Note that with Kerberos auth, either there's a valid ticket in the cache and the `hadoop-auth` lib will use it automatically; or you can use `UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab()` method to create a session ticket at run-time.